# jquery fadein recursion - how to detect complete and run callback

Tags: jquery

I need to run a callback after the following recursion is completed:

```
function fade_day_div() { 
    $("div#day").first().fadeIn("slow", function showNext() {
        $(this).next("#day").fadeIn("fast", showNext);
    });
};
```

Can I possibly use a deferred object here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to use deferred objects here, just this:

```
function fade_day_div() { 
  $("div#day").first().fadeIn("slow", function showNext() {
     var $next = $(this).next("#day");
     if($next.length > 0) {
         $next.fadeIn("fast", showNext);
     } else {
         ... your callback here ...
     }
  });
};
```

Answer (score 2):

A promise().done() might be the trick here (Although with the recursion I'm not sure).

```
function fade_day_div() { 
    $("div#day").first().fadeIn("slow", function showNext() {
        $(this).next("#day").fadeIn("fast", showNext).promise().done(function(){
               //Callback code here
        });
    });
};
```

Might work, might not.  Depends on how nested in recursion it is.